# Typescript property note

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I get this warning with my project. What am I missing?

```
[tslint] unused expression, expected an assignment or function call 
(no-unused-expression)
```

**property chosenList**

[image]

Comment: you are evaluating the equality of the 2 variables but don't to anything with the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `=` to assign value and not `==`